# Hide/Display label and textbox on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I am trying to hide/display label and textbox on the dropdown select.

So I No is selected, I dont want to display anything else

If 1 is selected, I want to display 1 label and 1 textbox 
If 2 is selected, I want to display 2 label and 2 textbox

What am I doing incorrect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkvalue(val)
{
if(val==="No")
{
   document.getElementById('guest_label').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('guest_name1').style.display='none'; 
   document.getElementById('guest_label').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('guest_name2').style.display='none';
}

 else  if(val==="1")
{
   document.getElementById('guest_label').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_name1').style.display='block';
 }
 else 
 {
   document.getElementById('guest_label').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_name1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_label').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_name2').style.display='block';
 }
   }
 </script>
 </head>
<body>

 <label for="guest_number">Any Guest: </label>
  <select name="guest" onchange='checkvalue(this.value);'> 



                <option value="No" selected >No</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>


 <label for="guest_label" style='display:none'>Other Guest Name: </label>
 <input type="text" name="guest_name" id="guest_name1" style='display:none'/>
<input type="text" name="guest_name" id="guest_name2" style='display:none'/>
</body>
 </html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the second label tag from

```
<label for="guest_label" style='display:none'>Other Guest Name: </label>
```

to

```
<label id="guest_label" style='display:none'>Other Guest Name: </label>
```

Your JavaScript code will fail at `document.getElementById('guest_label') .style.display='none';` when it it is not able to find element  whose id is 'guest_label'.

document.getElementById('guest_label') will return null and we cannot call `.style` for null value.

[Check](http://jsfiddle.net/6n2yeem7/) the corrected one.

Comment: Thanks this displayed what I want but it doesnot refresh if I click on 2 and click back to 1

Comment: Of course there is an attribute called for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label - the error there is it should be `for="guest_name1" `

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm sorry totally forgot. But his code logic was to operate on the id attribute, not on the for attribute. will update accordingly.

Comment: @user3897102 just add the style changes to else if block `document.getElementById('guest_name2').style.display='none';` check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6n2yeem7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code you posted was incomplete, you have no element with id "guest_label". JS returned an error when it tried to reference a property of element with that id, which is a null.

Comment: there is <label for="guest_label" style='display:none'>Other Guest Name: </label>

Comment: The "for" attribute refers to the id of the element that label is for. So, for example, you have a textbox with id "input1", and a label with "input1" for attribute for that textbox. The "for" attribute is mostly for semantics purpose, it is not the id for that label element. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: The `for` is to allow a click on the label to trigger the click on the id in the for. The code should have been `for="guest_name1"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include IDs for guest_label1 and guest_label2, and then toggle guest_label2 of 1 is selected.

```
<script>
function checkvalue(val)
{
if(val=="No")
{
   document.getElementById('guest_label1').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('guest_name1').style.display='none'; 
   document.getElementById('guest_label2').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('guest_name2').style.display='none';
}

 else  if(val==="1")
{
   document.getElementById('guest_label1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_name1').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('guest_label2').style.display='none';
   document.getElementById('guest_name2').style.display='none';
 }
 else 
 {
   document.getElementById('guest_label1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_name1').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_label2').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('guest_name2').style.display='block';
 }
   }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="guest_number">Any Guest: </label>
  <select name="guest" onchange='checkvalue(this.value);'> 



                <option value="No" selected >No</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>


 <label id="guest_label1" for="guest_label" style='display:none'>Other Guest Name: </label>
 <input type="text" name="guest_name" id="guest_name1" style='display:none'/>
  <label id="guest_label2" for="guest_label" style='display:none'>Other Guest Name: </label>
<input  type="text" name="guest_name" id="guest_name2" style='display:none'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but if I click on 2 and click 1 back, it doesn't refresh and still shows 2 labels and textbox

Comment: Hmmm, works on my end. I'd double-check and make sure your code matches my snippet.